# Is it possible to suppress a running total if there is only one record?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report that I am working on. This is more of an aesthetic thing but I still want it to work.

Is it possible to suppress the total if its only evaluating one record?

Thanks in advance, I am a crystal reports noob.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can do when you are building your collection for the report.
so at the time of building count no of records are returned and if record count is 1 then you can easily suppress that field in the code.

Give the total field name i.e txbTotal

and then suppress it in the code based on condition hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the total field, choose "format object", click the formula button beside the "suppress" check box, put the formula:

```
Count ({YourTableName.YourFieldName}) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can easiest way would be

Go to section expert of running total --> x-2 of supress and write below code.

```
onLastRecord
```

now run the report